# Apache 2.2 ProxyPassMatch RegEx

Tags: regex, apache, mod-proxy, apache2.2, proxypass

I would like to use Apache 2.2 ProxyPassMatch to make a Reverse Proxy.

Expectations: Exclude specified directories in the DocumentRoot and all others redirect to.

Example:

1. DocRoot

   - Project1

     - Dir1
     - Dir2
   - Project2

     - Dir3
     - Dir4
     - Dir5
   - Project3

     - Dir6

Redirect the "Project1" and "Project2" directories (and all files and subdirectories), but not redirect the "Project3" directory (and all files and subdirectories).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following set of rules:

```
ProxyPass /project3 !
ProxyPass / http://reverse.proxy-address.com/
```

Make sure that `mod_proxy` is enabled.

Comment: Thank's Your help! I know that it works, but I only solve the problem to the ProxyPassMatch directive.